# Find new users in specific range dates

Tags: mysql

I have a schema that is like this. All dates are mm/dd/yyyy

```
date
gameid
playerid
name
gender
```

**So I have to find the number of new male players that appeared in week 2. i.e. players that were in week 2 but not in week 1.**

```
**wk1 (07/01/2022-07/07/2022)** 
playerid   name
1          john
2          tom
3          sam
```

```
wk2 (07/08/2022-07/15/2022)
playerid   name
1          john
6          ben
7          dick
3          sam
```

So it should be just 2 since in week 2, ben and dick were not in wk 1. In excel one can just do a vlookup but in SQL i'm kinda lost. I did a left join

This is my query.

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct daily_player.playerid)
FROM daily_player left join
(
        SELECT playerid
        FROM daily_player
        WHERE gender='M'
        ) as t
    on DATEDIFF('2022-07-16', '2022-07-09')
```

I'm not exactly sure how do do a date range from 07/01/2022-07/07/2022 in the query to find those in wk 1 and wk2.

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses exists logic:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT playerid)
FROM daily_player dp1
WHERE gender = 'M' AND
      date BETWEEN '2022-07-08' AND '2022-07-15' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM daily_player dp2
                  WHERE dp2.playerid = dp1.playerid AND
                        dp2.gender = 'M' AND
                        dp2.date BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-07');
```

Comment: thanks lemme try it out! so a join isnt necessary? i was thinking somewhere along the lines of like 1 table, and the join will create a replicate on a diff date range, then do a comparison to see which is present in wk2 which wasnt there in wk1. thanks though!

Comment: strangely it didnt work. it returned me only the first range of dates. when i ran the query for the nested query separately, there were still the same values found within the first query

Comment: Somehow I feel the problem lies in your data, rather than in my answer.

Comment: hmmm, its possible. lemme look at it again. i checked it logically it makes sense, so im not sure why it didnt work. thanks though